# awk split column into multiple columns in staggered manner

Tags: awk, sed

I have a text file containing a single column of data as below :

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

I want to split this into multiple columns using awk or sed command as follows:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
```

How can I do this? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6):

here is another approach

```
paste -d' ' - - - < file
```

with `awk`

```
awk 'ORS=NR%3?FS:RS' file
```

also

```
pr -3ats' ' file
```

Answer (score 4):

This should work because `echo` is a default command for `xargs`

```
xargs -n 3 file
```

Answer (score 4):

Using `rs` - *reshape a data array*:

```
$ cat file | rs -C' ' 2 3
1 2 3 
4 5 6
```

- `rs` reads the standard input
- `-C` output column separator
- `2 3` rows and columns

Use `-t` to transpose the input:

```
$ cat file | rs -C' ' -t 2 3
1 3 5 
2 4 6
```

Answer (score 2):

With `sed`:

```
sed 'N; N; s/\n/ /g' file
```